# PostgreSQL prompts for password before setting one

Tags: postgresql, passwords, postgresql-9.6

I have just installed PostgreSQL 9.6.3 via homebrew(brew install postgresql) and am simply trying to run psql. However after entering:

**Mac-Pro:~ Travis$ psql**

It prompts me to enter a password, which I have never set. I've tried entering my system login password but receive:

**Password: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Travis"**

And when entering nothing I get:
**psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied**

Everything I've found online states there is no password set by default by postgres and yet this is requiring one and I've just installed it. No tutorial I've found mentions what to do if it prompts for password after install, they just jump right into working in postgres(usually creating users and settings passwords).  What could this password be if I've never set it up and it's not my system password? And really what I want to know is, how can I get past this and use postgres?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your postgres installation is probably using **ident** authentication mechanism.

Please check if a user named **postgres** is created in your system. If yes, try to execute **psql** by switching to that user and see if it works.

Comment: I did find the user **postgres** there, I had to reset the password for it but was able to login, however got an error **mac os x needs to repair library to run applications** I was still able to get to terminal and run psql but it did the exact same thing - prompted for password which I entered the new system password I just set up for **postgres** and it still says password authentication failed.

Comment: Could you please check the **auth-method** in your **pg_hba.conf** file? Changing it to **trust** and restarting postgres should allow all logins without prompting password if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: It appears the method is already set to trust.  When I open **pg_hba.conf** and scroll all the way to the bottom I see a sort of table with columns TYPE, DATABASE, USER, ADDRESS, METHOD.  Under method lists **trust** 6 times, there are no other values under METHOD.  Is there a row I should add there?

Comment: Do you see a line that reads **local all all   trust**? If not, please add it and check once. Also, try **psql -U postgres** instead of just saying **psql**.

Comment: okay I added the line **local all all trust** at the bottom and restarted postgres but both **psql** and **psql -U postgres** are still prompting for password.

Comment: Do you have a line that reads **host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust** as well? If not, please give that a try. Also, am sorry if am misguiding you. I had a similar problem long back and switching to postgres user worked.

Comment: Okay I added that line at the bottom as well, it did not exist before.  Same issue though.  No worries at all I really appreciate your help.  I can't believe how difficult this is just to set up! Everything I read online it seems that once installed it's pretty much good to go, it's frustrating that mine is apparently configured differently right out of the box.

Comment: If **trust** auth-mode doesn't work, shall we try **ident**? Please replace **local all all trust** with **local all all ident** in your **pg_hba.conf**, restart postgres and try once as **postgres** user.